# Cannot connect to postgreSQL docker container via postico

Tags: postgresql, docker, postico

I'm trying to use Postico to connect to a docker postgreSQL container on my local machine.

I've tried connecting to 0.0.0.0, localhost, and 127.0.0.1. Each give me the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

0.0.0.0 gives me a similar, but smaller error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.23
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

**Solution found thanks to Egor!** I forgot to specify `ports: - "5432:5432"` inside my docker-compose file. Rookie mistake ;)

Comment: Good catch. I just updated `docker-compose.yml` with port and worked for me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If postgres version doesn't matter, try to change Postgres image to this one, it works for me

And also make sure that you add ports in `docker-compose.yml`

```
postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports: 
     - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

P.s. updated to fix typo

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. I'm still getting a 'connection refused' error with postgres:latest.

Comment: Did you add ports in Postgres docker-compose?
    `ports:
    - "5432: 5432"`

Answer (score 15):

I also had issues using Postico to connect to my Postgres DB in a docker container.

Ultimately, my issue was that **I had a local Postgres DB running**.

As soon as I disconnected my local Postgres DB, I was able to use Postico to connect to my docker DB. With the host set to `localhost`, I used the `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, and host port as defined in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

[image: Connection Detail for Postico]

Comment: My instance of Postgres was running with homebrew. `brew services stop postgresql` fixed it.

Comment: Urgh, this has bitten me three times now, pg restarting and me not noticing. Thanks for posting.