# How to connect Postico with two postgresses one running locally and the other in docker-container?

Tags: postgresql, docker-container, postico

I have two postgresses running. One is running in the local machine and the other in a docker-container. I first had trouble connecting to the postgres running in the docker-container at all, but after following the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082443/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-docker-container-via-postico) I was able to connect to it after I had shut down my local postgres. Now my question is how could I have Postico connecting simultaniously to the local postico and the one that is running in docker-container, so that I can access databases in them simultaniously?

Comment: You should assign them different port numbers if you want them both running at the same time reachable on the same host.  Traditionally that would be 5432 for one and 5433 for the other.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.